# Looping HTML to parse Dictionary, but returning repeated value

Tags: python, html, dictionary, parsing

Parsing HTML.txt files, which are basically portions of HTMl. I have what I thought would work but it's repeating the same address for all the keys (locations). Can anyone spot a solution?

```
with open('AL.txt','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)


for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    
    for h in soup.find_all('h2'):
        location = h.find('a').text
        
        for p in soup.find_all('p'): 
            p = p.text.replace('\n','|').replace('\t','').strip()
            clean = ' '.join(p.split()).replace('| ','|').replace(' |','|').replace('||','|')
            address_clean = clean.replace('| ','|').replace(' |','|').replace('||','|')
            
            result[location]=[address_clean]

            
result
```

what I am getting right now:
[image]

Comment: `for p in soup.find_all('p')` will always return all paragraphs, no matter where in the document they appear. Your script is therefor always iterating over all paragraphs, continually overwriting the `result[location]`. You will need to find the next `<p>` after the current `<h2><a>`.

Comment: do you know how I can update my code to fix that?

Comment: Depends on the structure of your HTML code. Does the `<p>` directly follow the `<h2>` tag?

Comment: Just a guess: you might want to try `p = h.find_next_sibling("p")` instead of `for p in soup.find_all('p'): ` to get the next paragraph following the current Heading2. I would also recommend to add the locations and addresses to a new collection instead of reusing the `result` object, but this totally depends on the use case.

Comment: Just a general advice: you might receive more views and help if you accept answers as solutions by ticking the check mark below the answer that had helped you solve a problem. Right now I see that you haven't marked any of your question as solved.